# Horizontal alignment of equality signs written on different position of multiple equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, subequations

I want to align these subequations which have two equality signs occuring at different postions. I want equations with equality sign occuring at middlle to be aligned same and the equations with equality sign occuring at end to be aligned same.
My code is:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\E\left[2 \cdot (a_R(n)^2-R_{R1}) \cdot 2 \cdot a_R(n)\cdot x^*(n) \right]&=0
\intertext{Assuming the symbols in different symbol periods are uncorrelated, we get}
\E\left[a_R(n) \cdot x^*(n)\right] = k \cdot \E\left[a_R(n)^2\right]\\
k \cdot \E\left[2 \cdot (a_R(n)^2-R_{R1}) \cdot 2 \cdot a_R(n)^2\right] &=0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\E\left[a_R(n)^4\right] &= R_{R1}\E\left[a_R(n)^2\right]
\intertext{So, the value for $R_{R1}$ can be calculated as:}
R_{R1}&=\frac{\E\left[|a_R(n)^4|\right]}{\E\left[|a_R(n)^2|\right]}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

Output:

[image]

**The equation 4.12a,4.12c should have same alignment and 4.12b,4.12d,4.12e should have same alignment without changing of their positions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case), based on the `alignat` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
& &\mathllap{\E\left[2 \cdot (a_R(n)^2-R_{R1}) \cdot 2 \cdot a_R(n)\cdot x^*(n) \right]}&=0
\intertext{Assuming the symbols in different symbol periods are uncorrelated, we get}
 \E\left[a_R(n) \cdot x^*(n)\right] & = k \cdot \E\left[a_R(n)^2\right]\\[1ex]
& & \mathllap{k \cdot \E\left[2 \cdot (a_R(n)^2-R_{R1}) \cdot 2 \cdot a_R(n)^2\right]} &=0 \\[1ex]
  \E\left[a_R(n)^4\right] &= R_{R1}\E\left[a_R(n)^2\right]
\intertext{So, the value for $R_{R1}$ can be calculated as:}
  R_{R1}&=\frac{\E\left[|a_R(n)^4|\right]}{\E\left[|a_R(n)^2|\right]}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we have equations centered which are dragged to right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain more?  How can an equation be both centred and dragged to the right? Which (sub)equations are you speaking of?

Comment: I dont want equation to be dragged right i want them centered alignment

Comment: Each centred, but with two different alignment groups?

Comment: Yes thats what I want

Comment: I've updated my code. Is it more like you want?

Comment: What does && mean in alignment other than & operator?

Comment: and what is the function of mathllap?

Comment: @FaizanZaheer: An aligned environment with $n$ alignment points requires $2n – 1$ ampersand: each column of alignment but the first is introduced by an `&` and  in that column, the alignment point is marked with another `&`. As to `\mathllap`, it is like `\llap` in math mode. `\llap{\something}` inserts something on the left of the current point, but make it have 0pt. It is like `\makebox[0pt][l]{something\}`. It is this command which makes all rows more or less centred, while having two alignment points.